# Custom Post Type Front Page Gives 404

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, plugin-development, 404-error

I have developed a plugin on one site and just now moved it to another. At start I had that problem in the initial site too. Saving permalinks again solved it in the initial website.

I then moved it to the new website and I am getting it again. I tried to save the permalinks settings again but it isn't helping.

I saw multiple solutions but none solved the issue.

This is how I create the custom post type:

```
register_post_type( 'ossp',
    array(
        'labels'       => array(
            'name'       => __( 'Sale Page' ),
     ),
     'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'sale-page', 'with_front' => false ),
     'public'                   => true,
     'hierarchical'         => true,
     'has_archive'          => true,
     'publicly_queryable'   => true,
     'supports'     => array(
         'title',
         // 'page-attributes',
         'editor',
         'excerpt',
         'thumbnail',
        ),
    )
);
```

If any more information is needed, tell me and I'll edit the question.

Thanks!

Comment: How you are displaying the 'Sale Pages' on the front-end?

Comment: With a layout I've built, In the `theme-child` folder

Comment: Please share the `WP_Query` for this post type.

Comment: Where do I get it from?

Comment: Please conduct a [basic debugging](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/debug/info) first, then you might get a good way to proceed.

Comment: The new website is live, it'll be a bit of a problem to do some of the steps mentioned there. Is there another way?

Comment: By front page, do you mean archive? Your archive URL is `/ossp/`, is this what you are trying to visit?